# Why do many OO languages use the memory location of the object itself as the default hash code?

Tags: oop, hash, hashtable

Why do may OOP languages use the memory location of an object as a default hash code for instances of a class? If hash table will be smaller than the addressable memory.

Comment: hashtables typically don't map hashcodes directly to table indexes. The address is typically immutable and unique and costs nothing to compute making it a handy integer id.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's very convenient!

Memory address is a unique identifier of an object as no other object can occupy the same memory location. Hash table doesn't need to be big to use them. Suppose initially your hash table is small and has just 10 buckets. To decide which bucket to put your object in you take its address and `% 10`. And you have "good enough" distribution over buckets. Hash tables are really interesting thing and I'd recommend to read more about them, e.g. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).